# "command validateembeddedbinary failed with a nonzero exit code" on Mac M1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am currently developing Android and iOS using react-native, and I encountered an error **"command validateembeddedbinary failed with a nonzero exit code".** The service I am working on consists of four components: app, watch, widget, and it seems that this error occurs specifically with the watch component, but I am not sure. If anyone has experienced this issue or has any advice on how to resolve it, please help.

I am using a MacBook M1 and Xcode version 14.3.

[command validateembeddedbinary failed with a nonzero exit code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1NRz.png)

I have tried running "yarn react-native clean", uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling it from the App Store, and even cleaning the project using cmd + shift + k. However, the build is still not successful.

This error typically occurs when building the app on a real device, but not on the simulator. The build process may appear to complete successfully, but the error occurs when attempting to run the app on a connected device. :(